# I can't run Go programs anymore

Tags: go

This is the oddest problem I've ever encountered. I have my Go development environment set up on a Windows 2008 R2 virtual machine. I don't even restart it nor run Windows update.

Today I just realized that I can no longer run Go programs. I can successfully build and run unit tests with 'go test'. However, running any compiled Go program, (even hello world) causes a pop-up window titled 'Unsupported 16-bit application' to appear. The error message is as follows:

> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows
>   you're running. Check your computer's system information to see
>   whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the
>   program, and then contact the software publisher.

The result is the same regardless of what version of Go I use (x86/x64). Also note that I'm not using any IDE. I call go.exe to build/test from the command line.

I can't get my head around this since running 'go test' works just fine.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

Here's the console output when I build and run the program:

[build/run output](http://pastebin.com/EJMiNmMY)

Interestingly, dumpbin suggests that indeed there's something wrong with the executable

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>dumpbin /headers
C:\Projects \GoPlayground\src\playground\playground.exe Microsoft (R)
COFF/PE Dumper Version 11.00.51106.1 Copyright (C) Microsoft
Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Projects\GoPlayground\src\playground\playground.exe

File Type: LIBRARY
C:\Projects\GoPlayground\src\playground\playground.exe : warning
LNK4003: invali d library format; library ignored
C:\Projects\GoPlayground\src\playground\playground.exe : warning
LNK4048: Invali d format file; ignored

  Summary


C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0>
```

And here's the full source code:

```
package playground

import "fmt"
import "playground/another"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
    fmt.Println(another.Foobar(2))
}

-------------------

package another

func Foobar(i int) int {
    return i + 1
}
```

EDIT2:

I've reinstalled Go twice with no effect.

Comment: Show us what you do, e.g. with a simple hello world show which commands you run, where the files you compile are located and anything else of interest, such as the output of `go -version

Comment: Show us a reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, I've just added a lot more info.

Comment: If you restart the system, does the problem continue?

Comment: Yes, it does. I think something is really wrong from dumpbin's output. I just don't know how I could debug the build process.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Program execution](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)
>
> A complete program is created by linking a single, unimported package
>   called the main package with all the packages it imports,
>   transitively. The main package must have package name main and declare
>   a function main that takes no arguments and returns no value.
>
> ```
> func main() { … }
> ```
>
> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then
>   invoking the function main. When that function invocation returns, the
>   program exits. It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to
>   complete.

Use `package main`, not `package playground`. For example,

`playground.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "playground/another"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
    fmt.Println(another.Foobar(2))
}
```

`playground/another.go`:

```
package another

func Foobar(i int) int {
    return i + 1
}
```

Output:

```
Hello world!
3
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I recall renaming main to playground a few days ago. I never imagined it could have such dramatic effects. Thank you!