# "This version of %1 is not compatible.." error

Tags: windows, go, go-build

`fork/exec C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1624998878\b001\exe\main.exe: This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.`

This error is thrown whenever I try to run any go files.

I have tested with a simple "hello world" app:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

and tried various ways of building this (none of which work):

```
go run main.go
go build main.go
go build -o hello main.go
```

I already tried:

- excluding the go files and the work directory from windows defender and antivirus.
- reinstalling Go and Go extension from the vscode.
- Unsetting all Go env vars
- Running the same program with same env vars on another system (successful).

I checked the TEMP directory for the files and it does create new `go-build12xxx` everytime I run or build. But throws this error. I've already tried both  x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of Go though the OS is 64-bit Windows 10. The Go version is `go1.21.1.windows-amd64.msi`.

What could be the cause and solution of this?

`go env`:

````
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\user1\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\user1\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLCHAIN=auto
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.21.1
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
set GOMOD=D:\Inter\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build1803464262=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches```
````

Comment: «…I try to run any go files»–what does this mean, precisely?

Comment: Also please confirm that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951762/i-cant-run-go-programs-anymore) is not the issue you are facing.

Comment: @Brits, interesting. Do I understand correctly that `go build` run from an IDE called on a package not named `main` was forced to produce what looked like an executable image file (supposedly by supplying the `go build` the `-o` command-line parameter) but the result was a compiled go package which obviously cannot be executed?

Comment: Well, just recreated that. The file produced is an `ar` archive. I do not have Windows, and Wine fails execution with a different error message but still looks suspiciously close.

Comment: @kistix yep - I replicated it with a simple app. The error differs depending upon whether you are running it under powershell or `cmd` (the later gives the error stated in the question).

Comment: @kostix it meant the fault was not in the go file but in go env I guess. There was some error in GOPATH and GOROOT and I fixed that. After that, there was no issue executing .go files. But later when I tried to create a simple server, it gave this error. Then I tried to execute simple hello world program which also gave the same error. So I think the error is not in the program rather in the environment.

Comment: @Brits No, that's very different issue from this.

Comment: @cruelfool please share the code you are testing with (I'd assume a basic "hello world" app) and the commands you are using to build/run it.

Comment: @kostix
`package main

import (
 "fmt"
)

func main() {
 fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
`
Commands: go run main.go, go build main.go, go build -o hello main.go
None of it worked.

Comment: You must never touch `GOROOT` or any other env. var. maybe except `GOPATH`, but that one is not needed unless you're dealing with some dust-old version of Go (and you're using the latest stable one). Also, `go build` produces a fully self-contained executable in the sense it does not depend on environment. Can you retry with a clean-room environment? That is, make sure there's no Go-related env. vars set.

Comment: @kostix The error still persists even after unsetting all go env vars though I can run the same program with same env vars in another system.

Comment: I do not quite get that «run the same program with same env vars in another system»: the Go toolchain produces executable image files. They do not depend on any environment variables to run. Can you elaborate?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44817) may be relevant (same error occasionally output by internal go tests). Can you please add output from `go env` to your question and also confirm what files are in the current folder (to avoid confusion it's probably best to always build with `go build` and then run the executable).

Comment: @kostix Sorry, I meant go env. var.

Comment: @Brits Ok Done! There's only main.go and go.mod in the current directory and .exe file when `go build`

Answer (score 0):

1. The solution to this problem as I figured out is to build go file and run this in bash:
   `file ./main.exe` 
   It returns something like this:`./main.exe: PE32+ executable (console) Aarch64, for MS Windows` check whether **Aarch64** is compatible with your system.
2. Run `go env` and check the value of **GOARCH** & **GOOS**.For x86_64 device the value of GOARCH should be **amd64** not **arm64**. To find the list of possible platforms:
   `go tool dist list` which returns:

````
   android/386      freebsd/arm     linux/ppc64    openbsd/amd64
   android/amd64    illumos/amd64   linux/ppc64le  openbsd/arm
   android/arm      js/wasm         linux/s390x    openbsd/arm64
   android/arm64    linux/386       nacl/386       plan9/386
   darwin/386       linux/amd64     nacl/amd64p32  plan9/amd64
   darwin/amd64     linux/arm       nacl/arm       plan9/arm
   darwin/arm       linux/arm64     netbsd/386     solaris/amd64
   darwin/arm64     linux/mips      netbsd/amd64   windows/386
   dragonfly/amd64  linux/mips64    netbsd/arm     windows/amd64
   freebsd/386      linux/mips64le  netbsd/arm64   windows/arm
  
3. Choose which system is yours and change accordingly as per your system. Set the GOARCH values by running following in powershell as administrator:

 ```[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('GOARCH','amd64', 'User')``` for User variables
 ```[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('GOARCH','amd64', 'Machine')``` for System variables


PS: Though the value of GOARCH is amd64 in the problem, later I realised it was for that session only, not permanent one, hence it is very important to set it permanently. 
You can also refer to this:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/building-go-applications-for-different-operating-systems-and-architectures
````